# Enum type not being mapped to DB table

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5.0 Code First, in a .NET 4 library. Trying to set a class member to be of an `Enum` type, but it doesn't get persisted to the database, and no runtime exception occurs when EF is creating the database based on the code.

Of course, when I try to query against that Enum:

```
var departments = db.Departments
                    .Where(dep => dep.Name == DepartmentNames.English);
```

I get an exception saying:

```
The specified type member 'Name' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

I am using Microsoft's example of an Enum use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Are Enum members not supported yet? Does EF 5.0 differs somehow when hosted by a .NET 4 environemt than when hosted by a .NET 5 one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums where first introduced in EF 5 components that live in .NET Framework 4.5 (System.Data.Entity.dll). If you are using EF5 but target .NET Framework 4 there is no support for enums since they are not supported by the System.Data.Entity.dll that is part of .NET Framework 4. So, yes EF5 on .NET Framework 4 is scoped down when comparing to EF5 on .NET Framework 4.5. Some other features that are available when you target .NET Framework 4.5 but not available when you target .NET Framework 4 are spatial types, Table Valued Functions, strored procedures returning multiple resultsets and a couple more. An alternative is to move to EF6 (Alpha release shipped a few weeks ago) which does not depend on System.Data.Entity.dll and therefore supports all features that shipped in EF5 on both .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Framework 4 plus some more (e.g. async on .NET Framework 4.5). EF6 is an open source project from Microsoft and you can find all details here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/