# Using enums in fluent API

Tags: entity-framework-5

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490530/how-can-i-map-an-enum-using-entity-framework-4-1-fluent-api) asks about using enums with fluent API in Entity Framework 4.1, and it turns out that this wasn't supported.  Is this now supported in Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums are supported in EF5 for .NET Framework 4.5 and EF6 for both .NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 4.5 - you can find more details here: [Enum type not being mapped to DB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407957/enum-type-not-being-mapped-to-db-table/13443527#13443527). Enums are used in EF only for properties so you configure them in the same way you would configure primitive properties. Under the hood enum values are converted to the underlying enum type and stored in the database as values whose store type correspond to the underlying enum type (i.e. if an enum type has underlying type of byte each the values of properties using this enum type will be stored in SqlServer as smallint).

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationLogSeverity>().ToTable("ApplicationLogSeverity", "log");` gives me an error saying that `ApplicationLogSeverity` must be a reference type.

Comment: Enum types are not entities or complex types and cannot be configured separately - similarly to primitive types (e.g. for instance you cannot map int or string type to a table). You configure an entity that has an enum property which will be turned in a column on the table corresponding to the entity you have configured. Under the hood enums properties are treated as if they were primitive properties of the underlying type of the enum type.

Comment: So you can't create a lookup table using EF?  Or, you can, but it has to be a complex type, then.  That is good to know.

Comment: So then what's the best way to make a lookup table?  I'm concerned that a new instance will cause a new row, then, if we create a class to represent it.

Comment: How you would like your lookup table to look like? If it is just one column with int numbers that are keys at the same time how useful it is? I think you may want an entity with key column of enum type and a description. Otherwise - if you just want to have descriptive property values on the client side you don't need this table at all - you can just use enum properties on the entities. Keep in mind that enum values in your app are stored just as numbers in the database. Looking at the database you are not able to tell whether the corresponding property for a column is int or enum.

Comment: I would like a table that has an identity and a description.  The use of this is reducing the number of times the same text appears in the main table, since we'll have hundreds of millions of records in the main table.

Comment: If you want something like this you need to create an entity that has an enum property which would be the key and a string property for description. In general using enum types themselves for both is not really useful in my opinion due to limitations of names of enum values (e.g. no spaces allowed) - for look up tables you almost always want to have more descriptive name than the name of the value itself.

Comment: Not in this case- Information, Error, Exception, Start, Stop, etc.  Sounds like this isn't really supported by EF, though.  Looks like the best we can do is to create a table that EF doesn't know about and use that for joins to get the data - and keep the data in sync between the enum and the table.  Not ideal.

Comment: Do you use this database outside EF? I am not sure how great idea of this is but if you are not using the database outside the EF and the string you need is just the name of enum value you don't need a lookup table at all. Just use enum properties where they would have been foreign keys to the lookup table had you have one and do .ToString to get the value.

Comment: We will be using the database outside of EF.  I think I have the information that I need; if you add the information I put in my answer below (.NET 4 vs .NET 4.5) and the fact that they only get stored as ints, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: OK. Updated the response accordingly including a link to more elaborated answer on EF versions and enums.